# Rerouting old subdomain to new subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

After migrating a site to a new domain, the subdomain does not reroute. It should be rerouted from:

```
subdomain.oldsite.com
```

to

```
subdomain.newsite.com
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.oldsite.comt$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://subdomain.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any clues?

Comment: Do you have a typo? `^subdomain.oldsite.comt$` is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```